# How to enable evil-mode in Portacle?

Tags: init-file, evil, package

I want to start learning *Common Lisp* and I want to use [portacle](https://portacle.github.io/) for an IDE-like experience.

As I understand, portacle doesn't provide a normal `init.el` configuration file.
Instead, it uses a file in the `/config/` folder called `user.el`.

I tried to get started by adding this to my config:

```
;; Set up package.el to work with MELPA
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)

;; Download Evil
(unless (package-installed-p 'evil)
  (package-install 'evil))

;; Enable Evil
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

which fetches the contents from the evil-repository with MELPA.

This didn't work though. When I do this I get:
failed to download MELPA archive and a similar error as below: GNU-TLS error. I'm right away in the `scratch buffer` and I can't see the `CL-USER`-command prompt anymore either..

I also tried to install evil with `package-install RET evil RET`, but all I got was a

> GNU-TLS error: #, -12

So my question here:
How do I get started with evil-mode? I really don't intend to learn the emacs bindings.

Comment: In case  no answer can be found to the question. It has been surprisingly easy to set up the common lisp Sly-IDE in doom emacs. Maybe I'll use that instead.

Comment: "*In case no answer can be found to the question.*" -- You can email [the author of Portacle](https://github.com/Shinmera) or **open an *issue*** for help.

Comment: @shynur Ok I'll consider it.